# Retrieving deeply nested relations using bookshelf's withRelated()

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I have a `User` who can `belongToMany` `Group`, a `Group` can `belongToMany` `ReviewQueueStatus`, which `hasMany` `ReviewQueues`, which in turn `belongsToMany` `SavedSearches`.

I am trying to get the deeply nested relations for a User by doing

```
  return app.models.User.forge({
    id: req.params.id
  })
     .fetch( { withRelated: ["groups.review_queue_statuses.review_queues.saved_searches"]})
```

Currently this is only going one level deep. (ie: I can get all of the groups that a user belongs to and nested within each group is the list of all the `ReviewQueueStatus`'s).  The `ReviewQueueStatus` object has a `ReviewQueues` property but it is an empty list.  However, when looking at the DB row entries it shouldn't be.

Before I post all of the code and associated DB models is it possible to go deeply nested like this or can bookshelf only go one level deep?  I haven't been able to find anything in the bookshelf docs (https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html) that mentions anything about retrieving deeply nested relations.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bookshelf can reach any relationship level since you have models mapped correctly. By saying correctly I mean you need to set the correct association (one-to-one, one-to-many, etc) pointing to the correct foreign keys, and reference them with the same name in `withRelated` option in `fetch()` or `fetchAll()`.

Please post all the models so we can inspect them.